# iPhone - Apple Watch Sync (WatchOS 6) via CloudKit problem - Silent push notification

Tags: ios, synchronization, apple-push-notifications, apple-watch, cloudkit

I watch the WWDC video regarding keep iPhone and independent watch app (watchos 6) in sync. So I have made a simple cloudkit subscription on the Apple Watch on a record (watch os 6).

1) On the iPhone I modify the record, but when the iPhone is unlocked the notification is never send from cloudkit to the Apple Watch.

If I modify the record directly on the cloudkit dashboard and
2a) the iPhone is locked, then the silent notification is sent to the watch. -> great!
2b) the iPhone is unlocked, then it is shown directly on the iPhone. For user visible notification this behavior make sense, but in case of silent notification it doesn´t, because there is no way if you change settings on the iPhone App (iPhone unlocked), that you get a push to the watch (via the cloudkit subscription).

Does anybody have the same problem or any way to get this working with cloudkit?

Comment: Check ppix's answer in https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/126286